Given an ellipse rolling without slipping over an inclined plane, determine the point in which occurs lose of contact with the support plane.
I want to be able to solve the problem of determining the movement of an ellipse that rolls without slipping on a curve with a given profile. For this reason it seems convenient to proceed in the simplest case, when the curve is a straight line.

The ellipse is homogeneous with mass $m$, main axes $a$ and $b$ and inertia moment $I$. The plane is inclined by $\theta$. My first idea was to follow a Lagrangian procedure formulation as follows: Given the ellipse mass center with coordinates $(x,y)$ a rotated ellipse can be represented as
$$
\mathscr{E}(x,y,\phi) \to\left(\frac{x\sin\phi-y\cos\phi}{a}\right)^2+\left(\frac{x\sin\phi+y\cos\phi}{b}\right)^2-1=0
$$
To represent the rolling ellipse we need a translation such that $\mathscr{E}\left(x-u(\phi,\theta),y-v(\phi,\theta),\phi\right)$ so it rolls without slipping over the slanted plane.
The lagrangian then reads
$$
\mathscr{L} = \frac 12m(\dot x^2+\dot y^2)+\frac 12 I\dot\phi^2 -m g y + \lambda_1(x-u(\phi,\theta))+\lambda_2(y-v(\phi,\theta))
$$
$$
\cases{
u(\phi,\theta) = \cos\theta\int_0^{\phi}d\eta\sqrt{a^2\sin^2\eta+b^2\cos^2\eta}+\delta x = b \cos\theta E\left(\phi,1-\frac{a^2}{b^2}\right)+\delta x\\
v(\phi,\theta) = b \sin\theta E\left(\phi,1-\frac{a^2}{b^2}\right)+\sqrt{a^2 \sin ^2\phi+b^2 \cos ^2\phi}
}
$$
(See related link). Here $E$ is the Elliptic E function and $\delta x$ the coordinates difference between the rolling point and the mass center. Once solved for $\{x,y,\lambda_1,\lambda_2\}$, the zero crossing of $\lambda_2$ will point out the detachment.
I would like advice on the practicality of this approach, or ideas on alternative approaches.
